# Batch : Having FOR inside IF

Tags: batch

I don't know if that's possible so I'm asking you if I can put a FOR inside a IF in batch

```
@echo off

set alea=%random%%%100

echo Choisis la difficulte de 1 a 5 :

set /p level=

if %level% == 1 DO (
    for /f "eol=; tokens=1-5 delims=," %%i IN (levels.txt) DO (
        echo Level %%i
    )
)

if %level% == 2 echo lvl 2


pause>nul
```

Here is the result :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried it? did it work?

Comment: It's not complaining about the `FOR`, it's the `DO` it doesn't seem to like.

Comment: @Toto I edit my post so you have the answer now. It's no

Comment: `if %level% == 1 DO` is the problem.  Remove the DO and matching parens and put the for line in the same line as the `if %level% == 1`  also, surround your if like this `if [%level%] == [1]`

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah but I tried to find a way to do it but I didn't find

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I know but I need a way to make it work '^^

Comment: `if [%level%] == [1] for /f "eol=; tokens=1-5 delims=," %%i IN (levels.txt) DO echo Level %%i`

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thank you so much It does work !

Comment: Why I add the [] to the variables is that if %level% is EMPTY, you will get an error.  Happy to help/